# Most derived class cannot compile if virtual function not implemented, but can compile if one base class does not implement the virtual function

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions, overriding, virtual-inheritance

I have a C++ program with 4 classes : Person, Student, Employee, and PartTimeStudent.

Student and Employee each derive from Person, and PartTimeStudent derives from all 3 classes (making it the most derived class). Person, Student, and Employee also have a derived function called VDescribe().

Please see the code below :

```
class Person
{
    ...    
    virtual void VDescribe();
    ...
};

class Student : virtual public Person
{
    ...    
    virtual void VDescribe();
    ...
};

class Employee : virtual public Person
{
    ...    
    virtual void VDescribe();
    ...
};

class PartTimeStudent : virtual public Person,
    virtual public Student,
    virtual public Employee
{
    ...
};
```

Note : In the code snippet above I have omitted the Constructors, Destructors and member variables because they are not relevant to the problem at hand.

When I try to compile the code, I get the following errors :

```
override of virtual function "Person::VDescribe" is ambiguous

'PartTimeStudent': ambiguous inheritance of 'void Person::VDescrive(void)'

'PartTimeStudent': ambiguous inheritance of 'void Person::VDescribe(void)'
```

However, this only occurs if both Student and Employee implement VDescribe(). If one of the classes does not implement VDescribe(), compilation is successful. I still get warnings though, e.g. the following warnings occur if I omit VDescribe() from Employee :

```
'PartTimeStudent': inherits 'Student::Student::VDescribe' via dominance
```

May I ask why this occurs? I would like to know why PartTimeStudent is unable to compile if all 3 classes implement VDescribe(), but if either Student or Employee does not have the function, PartTimeStudent is still compilable.

Comment: in simple terms the problem is: which `VDescribe` should `PartTimeStudent` inherit when there are two possible choices?

Comment: ^- This. If you find it non-trivial to answer, imagine how the language designers feel.

Comment: @Angew, errors posted as text.

Comment: @tobi303 3 options - it inherits Person itself too!

Comment: @UKMonkey thanks for assuring me that I am not the only pedantic here :P

Comment: @tobi303 #helping :)

Comment: What do you expect to occur instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Two overrides

Imagine the scanario where `Student` and `Employee` implement `VDescribe`, while `PartTimeStudent` does not implement it. How would you expect this code to behave:

```
PartTimeStudent pts;
pts.VDescribe();
```

Which implementation of `VDescribe` should be called? It's ambiguous, which is precisely why the compilation errors out.

#### One override

When `Employee` does not override `VDescribe`, the situation is a bit different. `PartTimeStudent` then has the following functions to inherit:

- `Person::VDescribe` overridden by `Student::VDescribe`, coming via `Student`
- `Person::VDescribe` not overridden, coming via `Employee`.
- `Person::VDescribe` not overridden, coming via `Person`.

In this situation, `Student::VDescribe` overrides `Person::VDescribe` and is an unambiguous overrider, so the compiler is able to use it. However, it is warning you that there was an alternative inheritance path which did not go through this override. This warning is not very useful in practice, and is one of the few warning I routinely disable.

---

If you want your code to compile also in the case when both `Student` and `Employee` override `VDescribe`, you actually have to override it in `PartTimeStudent` too. The function will then have an unambiguous final overrider and the code will compile just fine. You can call one or both of the inherited implementations using qualified names. Example:

```
void PartTimeStudent::VDescribe()
{
  Student::VDescribe();
  if (isWorking()) Employe::VDescribe();
}
```

Comment: What I understand from your answer is :

If there is a single path of inheritance of VDescribe() from Person down to Student/Employee down to PartTimeStudent, compilation succeeds because PartTimeStudent uses the most derived version of VDescribe (either Person or Employee). 

But if there is a "split" in the path, i.e. after Person, both Student and Employee support VDescribe(). In this case, the compiler does not know which version PartTimeStudent will inherit, hence causing the error.

May I ask if this is what you meant?

Comment: "_This warning is not very useful in practice_" It's the dumbest warning ever. The compiler could has well output "you are using a complicate language, would you try GW BASIC instead?"